# .NET/Winforms: need an example for a nice UI for exception displaying

Tags: debugging, exception, user-interface

I'm writing a little developer tool which will (among other things) display exceptions thrown from the code that the tool is currently inspecting. Since it is a developer tool I would like to display as much information about the exception as possible (at the least type, message, stack trace and a recursive `InnerException`) and do it in a way that is easy to comprehend and analyze.

Unfortunately I cannot think of a nice UI for this. Are there any good examples out there? I have access to DevExpress components if that helps.

Comment: `considered subjective?` If it's any consolation, I got one too! ;)

Comment: @Benjol: that would affect the entire "user-interface" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the VS display, I'd look for:

- omit `null` values (such as HelpLink == null, or InnerException==null)
- Don't nest `InnerException`, it's basically a stack so represent it as such
- In StackTrace, you could make the file name clickable (or at least easy to pick out and copy).
- In StackTrace, Emphasizing the actual class and function name to make it stick out from the full namespace and signature garble.
- Some more data reduction is possible, e.g. exception type displayed twice, but this takes careful handling not to swallow information either

You could consider a HTML view, either making it interactive by catching clicks, or using javascript.

Comment: Hmm... you echo my thoughts about the HTML view. I think I'll try that. The highlighting part will be tricky though as I'll have to parse the string.

Comment: I'm sold. HTML view is far better suited for this task. I think I'll be able to come up with a decent view myself.

Answer (score 1):

Well the Visual Studio one does a fair job!  I can't seem to upload an image from this PC, but there's an [image here](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/DidyouknowYoucanexaminetheexceptionobjec_F317/image_6.png) if you haven't seen it.

Everything shown in a dynamic table/tree-like structure, you can drill down into inner exceptions etc, everything is copyable, and there are expandable viewers for certain things (e.g. stack traces).  Not pretty, but functional.

Comment: Since it is a .NET/Winforms application, I'm pretty familiar with VS approach to the problem. Though I believe it could be better, so I've created this question. However I will consider this (or some slight alteration of it) as well, if nothing better comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, make sure that the developer can copy and paste all the relevant information!